# How to get the head number (only a digital) in ConTeXt MKIV?

Tags: context, languages, context-mkiv

In my country, we usually don't use number 1, 2 ... as the head number (the section number, the chapter number and so on) but our own characters, for instance, the `一` stands for number `1`, the `二` stands for number `2`, the `十` stands for `10`.

Now, all my teachers, maybe you have known what I mean, I hope that I can get the head number, for example, the section number, so, I can define a macro called `\def\mysectionnumbers#1{...}` and pass it to the option `numbercommand` in the `\setuphead[section][...,numbercommand={\mysectionnumber},...]` so that I can change the section number into the `一` `二` above.

But, the `#1` in the `numbercommand = \...#1` is not only a digital, so I can't use the `\ifnum` or `\ifcase`. It seems like that it is the `...\getheadnumber...`. How can I get the head number and change it?

By the way, what's the replacement text of `\getheadnumber`?

Comment: Usually you can create your own number conversion with `\defineconversion[foo][A,B,C]` and then set `\setupheads[conversion=foo]`, but for some reason this fails for CJK ideographs.

Comment: @Marco Thanks very much. It can really work exactly! But I think the users should first define some typescripts and `\setscript[hanzi]`.

Comment: @Marco The `\defineconversion` and option `conversion` in `\setupheads` don't appear in the ConTeXt manual, where have you learnt this commands? Why I can't find this in contextgarden.net?

Comment: It probably appeared on the mailing list at some point, but it's on [the ConTeXt wiki - defineconversion](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/defineconversion), too. Actually, I just checked the source and the chinese conversion is already defined, check: `\dorecurse{42}{\convertnumber{cn}{\recurselevel}}`. But I still don't know why it fails within the head setup.

Comment: @Marco please wait for a moment, let me have a try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a font which contains the necessary characters all you need is
`\setupheads[conversion=cn]`. Here a full example:

```
\setupbodyfont [heiti]
\setscript     [hanzi]
\setupheads    [conversion=cn]

\starttext
  \dorecurse{6}{\startsection[title=\recurselevel]\stopsection}
\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: Yeah, that is it.